# MainActivity isn't starting up after successful login

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, android-activity, firebase-authentication

In my app, I had used Firebase authentication to sign in with google account. As the user signed in, the `MainActivity` should start, but this is splashing once and still showing the `login` activity.
Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name = ".BFD"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactSetup"
        android:parentActivityName=".ContextSetup" />
    <activity
        android:name=".EditContacts"
        android:parentActivityName=".EditContacts" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HowTo"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutDevs"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RecordHistory"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomText"
        android:parentActivityName=".ContextSetup" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ContextSetup"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
</application>
```

And the login.java as follows:

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {

private SignInButton signInButton;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                startActivity(new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };

    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.SignIn);
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                   // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();
        }
    });

    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w("Signing in: ", "Google sign in failed", e);
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        //Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        //updateUI(user);
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        //Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        //Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), "Authentication Failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }

                    // ...
                }
            });

}
```

}

What am I doing wrong here that is preventing the main activity to start.
Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think you need to create new OAuth Client in Google Developer Console for this project  with SHA-1 fingerprint and add the newly created google-json file to your app from firbase

Answer (score 0):

Are you updatng your activity when login has been successful. I see your updateUI method is Commented. And No statements are given to be operated on when user successfully logins.

Also Check your Auth Client ID as per your project.
Reply me back if it really helps you.

Comment: No mate i didn't used the updateUI() method. After i start the Mainactivity, then i used an GoogleSignInAccount object to get the last sign in activity, that did the job for me. :)

Comment: Are You Sure That FirebaseUser Object In Listener Working Perfectly. It may be culprit.
Try To Log The Items By Log.v("ActivityName","Login Start");
etc.
Then Tell me User is being saved or not By FirebaseUser

Comment: The user is being saved automatically :)

Comment: Are You Checking Out Same FirebaseUser Object In Main Activity ?
Even FirebaseApp.initializeApp Method Is Commented After Setting Your Layout As Content View

Comment: I never updated the question even after i make my own solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Use addAuthStateListener(AuthStateListener) and removeAuthStateListener(AuthStateListener) to register or unregister listeners.
Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

So i guess mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
is what you need after initializing your authStateListener.

Plus in the onComplete where you are setting the User,
I think that that is where you should call your new activity. I would recommend saving the user in an instance or passing it in the intent. Depends on your needs.

I did not try this, but a simple debugging and breakpoints in onComplete and the authStateListener would point you in the right direction.

Good luck, hope I helped.
on a side note classes and activities should start with a capital letter, LoginActivity (is the convention for an activity name)